# Prevent touchmove event only for x axis and let page scroll for y axis in Safari Mobile and Android

Tags: javascript, scroll, slider, touch, mobile-safari

I want to build a classical gallery where with the finger is possible to move the photo to left or right to see the next or previous photo.
I use jQuery binding the event touchstart, touchmove, touchend for calculate the positions of photos using the property event.pageX.
The problem is when moving finger the page begin to scroll. Immediatly the listener of touchmove stop to be invoked. 
To fix the problem I had put in the touchmove listener the call event.preventDefault() and the listener was invoked regulary and the page stopped to scroll.
I want that the finger can move the photo and at the same time can scroll the page.
I see in the apple website this happen regulary (see this page http://www.apple.com/osx/)
and even this script do the same http://iosscripts.com/iosslider-jquery-horizontal-slider-for-iphone-ipad-safari/

I want to know the concept behind the scene. I can't understand what I have to do to fix that.
I even try to use preventDefault and set the $(window).scrollTop by hand calculated by the pageY but the effects was very ugly.